# Plotly scale axis label units

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python

I am using plotly to plot a line chart of Data vs. Time.

I have:
x_data = [...] (nanosecond timestamps)
y_data = [...] (data values over time, corresponding to the timestamps)

When I plot y_data vs. x_data, my x axis labels are in nanoseconds as well. How do I change the labels so that they scale to seconds (s) instead of nanoseconds (ns)?

Please see my example code below.

```py
        data = [go.Scatter(
            x=x_data,
            y=y_data,
            mode='lines',
            marker=go.scatter.Marker(color='rgb(255, 127, 14)'),
            name='Data')]

        layout = dict(
            title=title,
            xaxis=dict(title=x_title),
            yaxis=dict(title=y_title),
            width=1200,
            height=500)

        self.charts.append(plotly.offline.plot(
            dict(data=data, layout=layout),
            output_type='div'))
```

Actual results: The chart x axis labels are in nanoseconds (ns)

Expected results: I would like to modify my code so that the x axis labels to be in seconds (s)